# An algorithm determining whether two subgroups of a free group are automorphic

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

In the book Lyndon, Schupp, Combinatorial Group Theory, the edition from 2000 P.30 They mention an unpublished work by Waldhausen that is said to give an algorithm to determine whether two subgroups are automorphic given their free generators. I searched for papers written by Waldhausen But I didn't find it. Has Waldhausen or anyone else published a solution to this problem? Where can i find it?

Comment: What does it mean that $H_1$ and $H_2$ are *automorphic*? See [automorphic form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automorphic_form).

Comment: Let $H_{1},H_{2}<F_{k}$ the they are automorphic if there exists an automorphism $\phi\in\text{Aut}(F_{k})$ s.t. $\phi(H_{1})=H_{2}$